Looking for CMD command line assistance re: multiple file prefix rename
I am currently attempting to use CMD.exe in Windows 11 to move a bunch of files to of a particular type and then automate the renaming of them all to add a prefix.   I tried using the following (in a batch file) but it ignores filenames that incorporate more than one word:
FOR /r "." %a in (*.png) DO REN "%~a" "May2024"%~nxa"
In this example, rename all .png image files to have the prefix "May2024".  However a filename like 'My Gear.png' for example is skipped/ignored.
Any guidance is appreciated.
See above. Currently resorting to Power Rename, part of the Microsoft Power Toys.
